# 「スタック・オーバーフローのマニフェスト」の誤字：どうすれは

Tags: バグ, 完了, ヘルプ

[スタック・オーバーフローのマニフェスト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)の見出しに「どうすれは」と書かれている箇所がありますが、これは「どうすれば」の誤りだと思います。

> ### どうすれは実現できますか？ プログラマー同士がお互いに敬意を表しながら。
>
> - ユーザーはサイトのコンテンツを改善しながら、模範に従ってコミュニティをリードする。
> - ユーザーは知識を仲間に教え、または無料でそれらを学ぶことができる。相互作用の結果、プログラミングの知識ベースはコミュニティ全体と共有されます。
> - ユーザーが互いに敬意を表しながら、安全に学習できる居心地の良い環境をサイト上で築く。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

早速下書きとマニフェストの誤字を訂正いたしました。（大変申し訳ありません、完全に見落としておりました。）

[image]